# Difference between zero-based Log-Sigmoid function and Log-Sigmoid function

Tags: neural-network

I have currently started to use NeuroXL Predictor Software in the Framework of a Project. I have also studied on the Basis of NNs and understand that the sigmoidal function is the type of activation function that is most preferable applied in a Network. I know how to differentiate between Log-Sigmoid and Hyperbolic Tangent as sigmoidal function - Log-sigmoid allows Output values to range between 0 and +1, whereas tanh allows for values between -1 and +1. The NeuroXL Predictor Software Offers an additional type of activation function, the zero-based Log-Sigmoid function. Think that I here I am Meeting the Limits of my mathematical knowledge - does sb of you know what exactly is meant by zero-based? Do they mean the fact that the slope of the sigmoid function is at 0? And is this somehow connected to the fact that the number of Neurons in the hidden layer is 0?

Sorry for this very Basic question, but I am not able to find a Definition of zero-based Log-Sigmoid function. I would appreciate any help and thanks in advance.

Comment: This question is not about a actual programming problem, so it might be more on-topic on [Computer Science](https://cs.stackexchange.com/).